# TestNG Framework Eclipe - log().all() not collecting Json Response properly

Tags: eclipse, maven, testng, hamcrest

For below code when I try to use `log().all()` json is not getting printed properly.

Method PUT - http://dummy.restapiexample.com/public/api/v1/update/6112

Request - {"name":"Ronak","salary":"123","age":"26"}

- Expected Response :

  ```
    {
        "status": "success",
        "data": {
            "name": "Ronak",
            "salary": "123",
            "age": "26"
        },
        "message": "Successfully! Record has been updated."
    }
  ```
- Actual Response in Eclipse Log:

  ```
    Response: 200
    Content-Length: 81
    {
        "status": "success",
        **"data": [

        ],** <--- **this value is missing here**
        "message": "Successfully! Record has been updated."
    }
    PASSED: testPUT
  ```
- My Code :

  JRE - JAVA 1.8 [ jdk - 8.0 of AdoptOpenJDK ]

  ```
    package restassuredTests;

    import java.util.HashMap;
    import org.testng.annotations.BeforeClass;
    import io.restassured.RestAssured;
    import org.testng.annotations.Test;
    import static io.restassured.RestAssured.*;
    import static org.hamcrest.Matchers.*;

    public class Demo3_PUT_Request {

        public static HashMap map1 = new HashMap();
        int id = 6112;

        @BeforeClass
        public void putData() {

            map1.put("name","Ronak");
            map1.put("salary","123");
            map1.put("age","26");

            RestAssured.baseURI="http://dummy.restapiexample.com/public/api/v1";
            RestAssured.basePath="/update/"+id;
        }

        @Test
        public void testPUT() {

            given()
                .contentType("application/json")
                .body(map1);

            when()
                .put()

            .then()
                .statusCode(200)
            .and()
                .body(containsString("success"))
            .and()
                .body(containsString("Successfully! Record has been updated."))
                .log().all();

        }
    }
  ```
- Pom.XML File Values:

  4.0.0

  ```
    <groupId>RestAssuredAPITesting_BDD_Project</groupId>
    <artifactId>RestAssuredAPITesting_BDD_Project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <name>RestAssuredAPITesting_BDD_Project</name>
    <!-- FIXME change it to the project's website -->
    <url>http://www.example.com</url>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>


            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                <artifactId>hamcrest</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>junit</groupId>
                <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
                <version>4.13</version>
                <scope>test</scope>
            </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/rest-assured -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>rest-assured</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/json-schema-validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-schema-validator</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/json-path -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.rest-assured/xml-path -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.rest-assured</groupId>
            <artifactId>xml-path</artifactId>
            <version>4.3.1</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.testng/testng -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
            <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
            <version>7.3.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
  ```